# How to write a component which outputs Markers of react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How a custom react component which outputs Marker on map should be written? I need to have smth like this working:

```
import MyMarker from './MyMarker.js';

const builtMarker = (function() {
  const position = [51.520, -0.11];
  return (
    <MyMarker position={position}/>
  );
})();

render(
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div className="map">
        <Map center={center} zoom={13}>
            <TileLayer
            url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            {builtMarker}
        </Map>
    </div>
  </div>
  ,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I made `MyMarker` component like that https://github.com/varya/react-leaftlet-test/blob/master/src/MyMarker.js but this gets error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined
```

I guess the component should not only  extend `MapLayer` but also provide special interface. What is missing? I could not find similar example in the docs.

Also, what should I do to output several Markers? I mean, in React it's required to be in a single wrapper. But it cannot be just `<div>` for the map. How this wrapper should be written?

PS: This is the repo where I demonstrate my case https://github.com/varya/react-leaftlet-test

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same exact problem and, reading the documentation I found out that I needed to add a `ref='map'` to the map component and then pass it down with a prop `map={this.props.map}` to the children components, linking them to the actual leaflet Map as you would using leafletjs.

What happens inside is that it tries to to a `map.addLayer(this)` or something like that, finding map as undefined

Answer (score 0):

For the current version of `react-leaflet`, ["React-Leaflet uses React's context API to make Leaflet elements available to other element that need it."](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/How%20it%20works.md). So the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined` indicates that the `layerContainer` could not be found (defaults to the leaflet map).

You can fix the error by sending the context accessed instance to the `react-leaflet` component

`<MyMarker position={position} layerContainer={layerContainer} />`